# Taming families of rate functions

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, asymptotics, limits-and-convergence

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$Let us say that a function $r\colon\R_+\to\R_+$ is a rate function if $r$ is nondecreasing and $r(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

Let us say that a family $(r_j)_{j\in J}$ of rate functions is *tame* if there is a rate function $R$ such that for each $j\in J$ we have $r_j(x)=o(R(x))$ as $x\to\infty$.

It is easy to see that every countable family of rate functions is tame.

> Is every family $(r_j)_{j\in\R}$ of rate functions tame?

Comment: The family of all rate functions is not tame. However, you ask for a family not larger than the continuum $c$. Ok, first, it is clear that we only need to look at the values on natural numbers. Then we can replace those values with natural numbers themselves. That brings us inside ${\mathbb N}^{\mathbb N}$. But we only need to look at strictly increasing functions, which means we are in a subset of the power set of $\mathbb N$ and that's close enough.

Comment: @Echo : Thank you for your comment. This may be a useful reduction. Does it lead to an answer to the question?

Comment: Yes, it gives a counterexample.

Comment: I think what Echo is saying is the following: The set of all "strictly increasing" (in a slightly modified sense) piecewise constant, on $[n,n+1)$, functions taking integer values is naturally parametrized by $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N} \cong 2^{\mathbb N} \cong [0,1]$. Our attempts to find an $R$ for this family can be restricted to functions of the same type. But clearly no $R$ can work (for example, because $r=R^2$ is in our family).

Comment: @ChristianRemling : I see. Thank you for your comment.